# Directory with read and write for a user is permission denied, but fine with execute permissions

Tags: ubuntu, users, groups, permissions

I have some weirdness with my users/permissions. I currently have a user named `world` that has the groups `world www-data admin`. I have a directory at `/var/abc` which has the permissions `0644` or `rw-r--r--`, the ownership of that directory is `world:www-data`.

For some reason, when I try to change into or list that `/var/abc` directory I get permission denied, however if I add the executable permission to the user, so it becomes `0744` or `rwxr--r--` I am allowed to access everything.

I can't figure out what is going on, could anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing is normal and expected behaviour. The `x` bit is required on a directory to enter it, search through it, or execute a program in it. As you are trying to cd into the directory then without the `x` bit being set you can't. When you set the permissions to 744, your user `world` who is the owner of the directory then has full control and as you observed an do what they want.

Comment: I thought that might be it, though wasn't sure. Thanks!! :)